# What is better ? Creating elements in html page or storing it in javascript object until required

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, object

I am creating a webpage which requires a lot of dynamic interaction.

There can be two ways to go about it -

**1. When a particular data comes in a particular tag, I add it to a javascript object and render it in html when the particular tag is clicked.**

**2. When a particular data comes in a particular tag, I create a dom structure ( div) with the data. The div is shown only when the user clicks on the tag**

Which of the above two cases would give better performance when talking in terms of 100 tags and data coming in every 1-2 seconds....

Can there be any better way ?

Comment: Try it! Performance needs to be tested, not inferred. 1) is probably more memory-efficient. If you are showing only one data set at once, you could also reuse the DOM structure which makes it even faster.

Comment: If the objects were big cumbersome things I'd be thinking about bringing them in via an Ajax call. That way you aren't chewing up lots of memory for things that aren't visible. However, if performance is absolutely key I would imagine hidden HTML is going to be the fastest method as you aren't manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Its preferable to have the data actually in the DOM if you want to support text/speech browsers and users without JS.